# Git Bash - ls show git repo folders

Tags: bash, git

I have a folder, /c/Tools, with three folders.

I want a command like below

```
$ ls --show-repositories
```

Tools is NOT a git repository, but Tools/MyProject and Tools/MyApp both are.  The output I want is:

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 0018121 Domain Users    0 Dec 14 14:33 MyProject/ (develop)
drwxr-xr-x 1 0018121 Domain Users    0 Dec 14 14:17 Data/
drwxr-xr-x 1 0018121 Domain Users    0 Dec 14 12:08 MyApp/ (master)
-rw-r--r-- 1 0018121 Domain Users 399K Aug  4 10:41 readme.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 0018121 Domain Users 136K Aug  4 10:20 image.jpg
```

so from the parent folder I can tell if a child folder is a current valid git repository (and what branch is currently checked out)

Thanks

Comment: or even better, since i think i can figure this out somewhat is how to get GIT to NOT print errors.  i call cur=$(git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD>&1); but if the current folder isn't a repository it echos the "fatal:..." message.  I'm trapping the result through $? so i don't WANT that message reported, since I am intentionally using the command to determine if the current folder is a repository.

Comment: You can eat stderr with `2> /dev/null`.

Answer (score 8):

Keep it simple; look for the directory `.git` and run your commands from within its containing directory.  Also throw in a `-print` to see what dir it is running in:

```
find . -type d -name .git -print -execdir git symbolic-ref --short HEAD \;
```

(Okay, actually `-print` shows the dir it *found*—`./path/to/repo/.git`, not the `./path/to/repo/` itself.  But that's a minor inconvenience.)

---

**EDIT: You can produce the EXACT output requested in your OP by the following:**

```
paste <(ls -ld *) <(for i in *; do if [ -d "$i"/.git ] ; then echo "($(git --git-dir="$i"/.git symbolic-ref --short HEAD))"; else echo; fi; done)
```

This doesn't have any real drawback that I can see.

By design it only finds top level git repos, i.e. if your "Data" directory (in your example `ls` output) has subdirectories which are git repos they won't be listed, whereas with the `find` command I gave earlier they would be.  But as I say that's by design.

This doesn't preserve colors in the output of `ls`.  You can do this by adding a `--color=always` to the embedded `ls` command:

```
paste <(ls -ld --color=always *) <(for i in *; do if [ -d "$i"/.git ] ; then echo "($(git --git-dir="$i"/.git symbolic-ref --short HEAD))"; else echo; fi; done)
```

Though, for some reason, this produces an extra newline at the end of all the output.  Oh well; not a big deal IMO.

---

For Mac OS, `ls` doesn't have a `--color` flag, so use the following to force color output:

```
paste <(CLICOLOR_FORCE=true ls -ld *) <(for i in *; do if [ -d "$i"/.git ] ; then echo "($(git --git-dir="$i"/.git symbolic-ref --short HEAD))"; else echo; fi; done)
```

Comment: (I explored doing the whole thing in a `for i in *` loop, but then the formatting for `ls -ld` doesn't line up as the output for each file is formatted separately.)

Answer (score 0):

May be something like that:

```
find YOUR_DIR -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec echo -n "{}  " \; -exec git --git-dir={}/.git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD \;
```

Example output:

```
.  fatal: Not a git repository: './.git'
./zabbix2  master
./dnsmasq  fatal: Not a git repository: './dnsmasq/.git'
./puppet-network  master
./resolv_conf  fatal: Not a git repository: './resolv_conf/.git'
./old  fatal: Not a git repository: './old/.git'
./php_ini  fatal: Not a git repository: './php_ini/.git'
./stdlib  fatal: Not a git repository: './stdlib/.git'
./mcollective  master
./netlogon  master
./debian  master
./apt  fatal: Not a git repository: './apt/.git'
```

You can play with first 'exec' command to change needed folder output format.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

I will say I that "--git-dir" option was new to me and that did the trick.
Now for the fun part.
Here is my *complete* answer, which is a combination of other queries here.  If anyone knows a way to speed this up, that would be excellent.

```
alias ls='ls -FHlAt --color --show-control-chars --group-directories-first'
alias lsdif='ls | xargs --delimiter="\n" ~/.config/lsdif_colors.sh'

#################
# lsdif_colors.sh
#################
for fileLine in "$@"
do
    if [[ $fileLine == total* ]]; then echo $fileLine;
    else 
        cols=($fileLine);

        cw=(-10 -1 -7 -6 -5 4 -3 2 -5 0);               
        for ((i=0 ; i < 9; i++))
        do
            printf "%${cw[i]}s " ${cols[i]}
        done

        name=${cols[@]:9}
        if [[ -d .git ]]; then 
            difType=$(git diff --name-status ./$name)
            if [[ ${difType:0:1} = "M" ]]; then printf "%1s \e[34m%s\e[0m\n" ${difType:0:1} "$name"
            elif [[ ${difType:0:1} = "D" ]]; then printf "%1s \e[31m%s\e[0m\n" ${difType:0:1} "$name"
            elif [[ ${difType:0:1} = "A" ]]; then printf "%1s \e[32m%s\e[0m\n" ${difType:0:1} "$name"
            else printf "   %s\n" "$name"
            fi;
        elif [[ $fileLine == d* ]]; then 
            d=$(echo ${name:0:((${#name}-1))} | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g")
            branch=""
            if [[ -d $d/.git ]]; then 
                branch="("$(git --git-dir="$d"/.git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD>&1)")"
            fi;
            printf "   %s \e[36m%s\e[0m\n" "$name" "$branch"
        else printf "   %s\n" "$name"
        fi;     
    fi;
done
```

this allows me to see a general view of a directory with one command, however, it does go a little slow.  I'm not expecting the same speed as ls, but lsdif is choppy.  if it can be sped up, great.  if not, *shrug* oh well.

Thanks
Jaeden "Sifo Dyas" al'Raec Ruiner

Comment: Re "If anyone knows a way to speed this up...": What does this script do that my `paste` one-liner doesn't?  The `paste` command (a) is very very fast and (b) produces the exact output requested in your question.

Comment: @Wildcard if you notice that this function is not the exact output of my question.  My question was only a part of this output, as this script also prints out the git diff status for files, so i can see in one command, which folders are repositories, and if i'm in a repository, which items have been altered.  my next phase will be to add an unstaged check to this script so I can see those as well.