# Shell: Changing ls color output if folder is Git repo

Tags: shell-script, shell, rhel, colors

My distro is RHEL so I have a DIR_COLORS folder and an LS_COLORS variable. I know how to modify the colors. I also know how to check if a folder is a git repo. What I don't know is how to have ls change the color of the directory if that folder is a repo (default is blue, the repo folder would be purple or something).

Here's my attempt at bad sudo code

```
for d in ls
    if git_repo($d)
        LS_COLORS = git_colors
    else
        LS_COLORS = normal
    print ls[$d]
```

I know that probably doesn't make "legal" sense but hopefully you get the gist. I know I can manually do it by echo'ing it out in a single column and manually changing the text color (in theory) but I want it to look like a normal ls with multi columns.

If there's a better way I'll take it. I also want to throw this into my bashrc into a function so I can alias ls to that function

Comment: These are already provided as standalone projects that you simply wire up in your ~/.bash_profile` - https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt.

Comment: It's also included with Git - https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh. The directions on how to set this up are at the top of the file.

Comment: Related: [Git Bash - ls show repo folders](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/249363/117037)

Comment: @wjandrea that command is almost exactly what I need. It has the problem of putting everything in a single column which is something I wanted to avoid

Answer (score 1):

#### Git prompts

Rather than roll your own here I'd recommend using what's provided by the Git project out of the box.

On a CentOS 7.x box if you `yum install git` everything is already included with Git to do both commandline completion + the git prompt.

```
$ rpm -ql git|grep completion
/etc/bash_completion.d
/etc/bash_completion.d/git
/usr/share/doc/git-1.8.3.1/contrib/completion
/usr/share/doc/git-1.8.3.1/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash
/usr/share/doc/git-1.8.3.1/contrib/completion/git-completion.tcsh
/usr/share/doc/git-1.8.3.1/contrib/completion/git-completion.zsh
/usr/share/doc/git-1.8.3.1/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh
/usr/share/git-core/contrib/completion
/usr/share/git-core/contrib/completion/git-completion.tcsh
/usr/share/git-core/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh
```

Here's the steps to do this manually, they'd need to be added  your `~/.bash_profile` to make them permanent.

```
$ . /usr/share/git-core/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh
$ mkdir somedir && cd somedir
$ git init
$ PS1="$GREEN\t$RED-$BLUE\u$YELLOW\w\[\033[m\]$MAGENTA\$(__git_ps1)$WHITE \$ "
```

Doing the above will set your prompt so that it goes from this:

```
[root@centos7 somedir]#

-to-

13:18:42-root/home/vagrant/somedir (master) $
```

**NOTE:** it's now displaying the branch that I'm currently on in this repo, in my prompt.

#### Where's the colors?

To get this colored you need to define the colors so that the variable `PS1` for the prompt's color variables have corresponding escape codes for their respective colors:

```
RED="\[\033[0;31m\]"
YELLOW="\[\033[0;33m\]"
GREEN="\[\033[0;32m\]"
BLUE="\[\033[0;34m\]"
MAGENTA="\[\033[0;35m\]"
WHITE="\[\033[0;37m\]"
```

Now reset the `PS1` again to pick these up:

```
13:24:26-root/home/vagrant/somedir (master) $ PS1="$GREEN\t$RED-$BLUE\u$YELLOW\w\[\033[m\]$MAGENTA\$(__git_ps1)$WHITE \$ "
13:24:35-root/home/vagrant/somedir (master) $
```

And it'll look like this now:

[image: ss#1]

#### And what about changing the color of `ls`?

If is probably something I'd discourage your from because you need to then run a `git status` against every directory in each `ls` command to determine if it's a Git repo or not.

Imagine this:

```
$ ls somedir
dir1
dir2
dir3
dir4
dir5
dir6
dir7
```

would result in 7 `git status` commands to determine which directory is a Git repo and which is not, so that you can decide whether to color it as purple or not.

Comment: This is definitly useful for if I'm inside a repo. However my question is specific to if I'm in a parent directory where I have folders that some are cloned repos and some arent. From what I could tell you don't neccessarily need to do a git status against each one. What I've done in the past is cd, do if [ -d .git ] , and then you know if it's a repo